# re-set scroll-snap-type after setting to "none" has no effect

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, jquery-animate

The latest version of Chrome, 69, now supports scroll-snap-type, but apparently not very well.

The original CSS:

```
    .carousel {
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    }
```

Using jQuery to animate the transition:

```
$(".carousel").css("scroll-snap-type", "none");
$(".carousel").animate({
    scrollLeft : 1000,
}, {
    complete : function() {
        // fail:
        $(".carousel").css("scroll-snap-type", "x mandatory");
    }
});
```

If we don't do this, then the animation snaps to each element in the carousel, making it appear very jerky, not smooth.  So, we disable the scroll-snap-type CSS first.  This works great.  The only trouble is, Chrome ignores the instruction to re-set this property to its original value!

I am told this works in Safari.

Any thoughts, solutions, workarounds would be most welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Well, Chrome is buggy, but at least we have a workaround:

new CSS:

```
        .item-carousel {
            scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
        }

        .snap {
            scroll-snap-align: start;   
            scroll-snap-stop: always;
        }
```

new HTML:

```
<div class="item-carousel">
    <div class="item snap" >
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and new JS:

```
$(".item").removeClass("snap");
$(".item-carousel").animate({
    scrollLeft : 1000,
}, {
    complete : function() {
        $(".item").addClass("snap");
    },
});
```

The new idea is, instead of manipulating the scroll-snap-type property on the container, add and remove the "snap" class on the contained items.  Somehow, this works.